# Approximating the smallest positive root of a function

Tags: algorithms, numerical-methods, roots

Suppose we have a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Let $S$ denote the set of all positive roots of $f$ and let $x^*$ denote the minimum of $S$ (assuming such a thing exists). What is the most efficient algorithm known that will approximate $x^*$?

Comment: Good luck!  When you find an automated method that finds the positive roots of $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}\sin(1/x^2)$, without human knowledge of the periodicity, let me know.

Comment: This may be a better question for [scicomp.se].